# Running sqlplus in background in Unix

Tags: sql, linux, database, unix, sqlplus

I am trying to run an `.sql` file from `sqlplus` in Unix environment as a background process.

I am connecting to Unix using Tectia or Putty, and I want `sqlplus` to continue running in background even if my terminal closes.

This command works

```
$ sqlplus USERNAME/password@SCHEMA
SQL>@test.sql
SQL> quit
```

but when trying to start it in background it fails

```
$ sqlplus USERNAME/password@SCHEMA&
SQL>@test.sql
SQL> quit
```

What is the right command/script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`&` will put it in the background

but if you actually want to close your terminal and leave for the day

you need to use `nohup`

```
nohup sqlplus USERNAME/password@DBNAME @test.sql &
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution. Do double-check that when you run the same command (without NOHUP and &) runs **without** any user input. Ideally, the SQL script, or the command you supply to NOHUP, should terminate by itself. I'm saying cause it is easy to let your SQLPLUS session hang, because the SQL script does not have any `EXIT`, or the command specified after NOHUP either doesn't. I would put any commands in a script, then call `NOHUP myscript &`, but that is something to check yourself. For example, you have a password that can be seen by any user on that OS, via `PS -EF`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the script name in the SQLPlus command line:

```
sqlplus USERNAME/password@SCHEMA @test.sql &
```